# How to load all objects of pickle in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I use pickle module,I can use `pickle.dump()` method to save many objects in file. But when I use `Pickle.load()`,this method only can load one object.What I should do when I want to load all objects?

Comment: What all objects? You just have to load only one file even if dumping creates multiple objects while dumping

Comment: Please give a **code** example of what your are doing and why/what is not working as expectd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer indicates that you are using multiple invocations of `dump` to dump multiple objects into the same stream. If that is the case, it is expected that you know how many times to call `load`, e.g. by obtaining the information from the first loaded object, or by the number of objects being constant.

If that is not the case, use a single `dump` to dump all the objects by packing them up in a tuple:

```
pickle.dump((a, b, c), f)
```

You then will be able to load them in one go:

```
a, b, c = pickle.load(f)
```

If you cannot change the dumping code to use a tuple, you can simply load the data from the stream until encountering an `EOFError`:

```
objs = []
while True:
    try:
        o = pickle.load(f)
    except EOFError:
        break
    objs.append(o)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer can solve my question.

Comment: For future reference. This answer solved my issue on how to **load multiple items from scrapy crawl to pickle** with `with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    objs = []
    while True:
        try:
            o = pickle.load(f)
        except EOFError:
            break
        objs.append(o)`